# PHPUnit error: the given data failed to pass validation

Tags: php, laravel

So I was following a Laracasts video where I got to lesson 10. I have followed the video closely any can't get my validation to pass. When Irun PHPUnit, I  get the following error:

> > :
>
> 1) CreateThreadsTest::a_thread_requires_a_title
>   Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data failed to
>   pass validation.
>
> /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php:105
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php:55
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/app/Http/Controllers/ThreadController.php:44
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:55
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:44
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:203
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:160
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:559
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php:43
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:65
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:64
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:59
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:561
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:520
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:498
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:174
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:148
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:149
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:234
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:84
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/tests/Feature/CreateThreadsTest.php:68
>   /home/vagrant/Code/forum/tests/Feature/CreateThreadsTest.php:37

Here is my ThreadController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Thread;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ThreadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
    }

    public function index()
    {   $threads = Thread::latest()->get();
        return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('threads.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required'

        ]);
        $thread = Thread::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'title' => request('title'),
            'channel_id' => request('channel_id'),
            'body' => request('body'),

        ]);
        return redirect($thread->path());
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Thead  $thead
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($channelId, Thread $thread)
    {
        return view('threads.show', compact('thread'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Thead  $thead
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Thead $thead)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Thead  $thead
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Thead $thead)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Thead  $thead
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Thead $thead)
    {
        //
    }

}'
```

Here is my TestCase.php file:

```
    <?php
namespace Tests;
use App\Exceptions\Handler;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->disableExceptionHandling();
    }
    protected function signIn($user = null)
    {
        $user = $user ?: create('App\User');
        $this->actingAs($user);
        return $this;
    }
    // Hat tip, @adamwathan.
    protected function disableExceptionHandling()
    {
        $this->oldExceptionHandler = $this->app->make(ExceptionHandler::class);
        $this->app->instance(ExceptionHandler::class, new class extends Handler {
            public function __construct() {}
            public function report(\Exception $e) {}
            public function render($request, \Exception $e) {
                throw $e;
            }
        });
    }
    protected function withExceptionHandling()
    {
        $this->app->instance(ExceptionHandler::class, $this->oldExceptionHandler);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and here is my CreateThreadsTest.php file

```
    <?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;
class CreateThreadsTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /** @test */
    function guests_may_not_create_threads()
    {

        $this->expectException('Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException');

        $this->get('/threads/create')
            ->assertRedirect('/login');
        $this->post('/threads', [])
            ->assertRedirect('/login');
    }

    /** @test */
    function an_authenticated_user_can_create_new_forum_threads()
    {
        $this->withExceptionHandling()->signIn();
        $thread = make('App\Thread');
        $response = $this->post('/threads', $thread->toArray());
        dd($response->headers->get('Location'));

        $this->get($response->headers->get('Location'))
            ->assertSee($thread->title)
            ->assertSee($thread->body);
    }

    /** @test */
    function a_thread_requires_a_title()
    {

        $this->publishThread(['title' => null])->assertSessionHasErrors('title');
//   $this->withExceptionHandling()->signIn();
//
//   $thread = make('App\Thread', ['title' => "A"]);
//
//
//
//   $this->post('/threads', $thread->toArray());
    }

    /** @test */
    function a_thread_requires_a_body()
    {
        $this->publishThread(['body' => null])
            ->assertSessionHasErrors('body');
    }

    /** @test */
    function a_thread_requires_a_valid_channel()
    {
        factory('App\Channel', 2)->create();
        $this->publishThread(['channel_id' => null])
            ->assertSessionHasErrors('channel_id');
        $this->publishThread(['channel_id' => 999])
            ->assertSessionHasErrors('channel_id');
    }

    protected function publishThread($overrides = [])
    {
        $this->withExceptionHandling()->signIn();
        $thread = make('App\Thread', $overrides);
        return $this->post('/threads', $thread->toArray());
    }

}
```

As you can see this is the code I copied from the Laracasts videos. As you can see, the validation fails on the threads controller even though I enable ExceptionHandling for the title. This is weird indeed. How do I properly enable exception handling for the title? Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing these instead...

TestCase.php file:

```
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->disableExceptionHandling();
        $this->withExceptionHandling();
    }
```

CreateThreadsTest.php

```
function an_authenticated_user_can_create_new_forum_threads()
{
    $this->withExceptionHandling()->signIn();
    $thread = make('App\Thread');
    $response = $this->post('/threads', $thread->toArray());

    $response->get($response->headers->get('Location'))
        ->assertSee($thread->title)
        ->assertSee($thread->body);
}
```